# Are there intrinsically weaknesses in accessing a same payload encrypted with different keys?

Tags: encryption, aes, password-cracking, decryption

Assume we use AES256 to encrypt the same payload 100 times, each with a different key.

An attacker gains access to the 100 encrypted payloads, and nothing else.

Is there some way the attacker can gain insight about the payload (or about the keys) based on those 100 encrypted payloads?

What about accessing 1 million encrypted payloads?

Comment: I suggest to move this question to the [Crypto SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The answer here, in a purely academic sense, depends on the mode of encryption. What mode are you thinking of here? If you're not sure what a "mode" is in this context, take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation